# Python debugging, but nothing come out if the code is running

Tags: python

Assume that you have written the following code to find the middle element from a 3-element list.

```
def findmiddle(a):
    if ((a[0] >= a[1]) and (a[1] >= a[2])) or ((a[0] <= a[1]) and (a[1] <= a[2])):
     return a[1]
    elif ((a[0] >= a[2]) and (a[2] >= a[1])) or ((a[0] <=a[2]) and (a[2] <= a[1])):
     return a[2]
    else:
     return a[0]
```

Notice that if a list is passed in that is not of length at least 3, the code will give an error.
Modify the function so that it will raise an exception if the list is not valid.
Then, show how you could call the function, printing a message if there was an exception.

Can you tell how can i raise exception if there's nothing come out if I run this code?

Comment: seems like homework, you should make it explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the function raise an exception and in the main program catch that exception... Like this

```py
def findmiddle(a):
    assert len(a)>=3, "Invalid"

    if ((a[0] >= a[1]) and (a[1] >= a[2])) or ((a[0] <= a[1]) and (a[1] <= a[2])):
        return a[1]
    elif ((a[0] >= a[2]) and (a[2] >= a[1])) or ((a[0] <=a[2]) and (a[2] <= a[1])):
        return a[2]
    else:
        return a[0]

L1, L2 = [1,2], [i for i in range(1, 11)]

try:
    print(findmiddle(L2))
    print(findmiddle(L1))
except AssertionError:
    print("List not big enough.")
```

Comment: thankyou so much your such a big help, by the way, can i know what is assert function for?

Comment: @MapleTree The `assert` statement checks the given condition, if the given condition is met, the program runs, otherwise it raises an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check at the start of the function like so :

```
if len(a) < 3:
    raise ValueError("Your list is not big enough. Must be length 3 or more")
```

Comment: Hi chuk the code is still not displaying anything, i've tried to get the input from the user but it's not ended up well

Comment: Are you actually calling the method itself? Just defining it is not enough to execute it.

Comment: a = print(input("Type number in a list: "))

def findmiddle(a):

  if ((a[0] >= a[1]) and (a[1] >= a[2])) or ((a[0] <= a[1]) and (a[1] <= a[2])):
    return a[1]
  if len(a) < 3:
    raise ValueError("Your list is not big enough. Must be length 3 or more")
  elif ((a[0] >= a[2]) and (a[2] >= a[1])) or ((a[0] <=a[2]) and (a[2] <= a[1])):
    return a[2]
  else:
    return a[0]      so far this is my progress, and im having a hard time excuting the method

Comment: At the absolute end of your file (underneath the function, with no indentation), add this `findmiddle(a)` and run it again. That should execute it.

Comment: but it will give an type error